# ng-content's "select" does not work if its targeted element is in a router-outlet

Tags: angular, router-outlet

see this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2nvs34

You can see I have `<ng-content select="app-grand-child-content"></ng-content>` to select the defined component. Sadly, this does not work if the target component of ng-content's select is in a `<router-outlet>`. You can toggle the comments in the `AppComponent` to see that it works if the component is declared "directly".

Why is this so and how can I achieve my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the router-outlet tag instead! I added some logic to your stackblitz. There is an additional grand-child route along with a click event that routes to it to prove the concept. Hope this is what you are looking for!

[Modified StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2nvs34?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: This is not an option since it it does not have to be in a router-outlet.